# In Win API how to get position of progressbar of another application, if it realized by TPanel of Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, progress-bar, tpanel

need to get position of progress-bar of another application. MS Spy++ points that is TPanel. It can change colour and has numeral position state. How to get all of this in Win API?

Comment: You'll need to ask the author of that control. Only the standard Win32 progress bar has a standard interface you can use.

Answer (score 1):

The [`TPanel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel) component is not the Delphi wrapper for the [`Windows Progress Bar Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you are getting and using the wrong class, instead search for the [`TProgressBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar) class, from here you can use any of the [`Progress Bar Messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the proper windows handle and the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. For example to retrieve the current position of the progress bar use the [`PBM_GETPOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: Unless the "progress bar" is implemented by custom-drawing the `TPanel`, in which case this approach will not work, and the only way to get the progress information will be to parse the onscreen pixels of the `TPanel`.